# JavaScript: new objects of the same class as keys for a dictionary

Tags: javascript

I tried the following, but the dictionary only had one key.

```js
class dog {}
dic = {}

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  dic[new dog()] = i;
}

for (var item in dic) {
  console.log(dic[item]);
}
```

But that was not what I intended. I wanted it to work like the following C# code, whose output is `0 1 2`. It seems that each `new dog()` in the JS code above is treated as the same object and thus the value overwrites the previous one. How can I modify the JS code so that it work like the C# code below?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class dog
{
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var dic = new Dictionary<object,int>();

        for(var i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            dic[new dog()] = i;
        }
        
        foreach(var item in dic.Keys)
        {
          Console.WriteLine(dic[item]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Object keys can only be strings. You can use objects as the keys in a `Map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using an object as a key in a dictionary (or an object in JS), it will be coerced to string(`"[object Object]"`)(except if it is a *[`Symbol`](https://javascript.info/symbol)* type) and will be treated as the same key and keeps getting overridden and you will get the final output as `2`. You can use a *[`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)* instead of an object as a dictionary to achieve your purpose.

```js
class Dog {
}

const map = new Map();

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    map.set(new Dog(), i);
}

for (const [key, value] of map.entries()) {
    console.log(value);
}
```